# Error between nginx and nestjs authentication part

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, nginx, nestjs

I try to use a NestJS backend with a Nginx reverse proxy.
I have coded an authentication part in my NestJS backend.

My problem is that when I used my frontend / backend in local mode, all is ok.
When I use it through Nginx, I always retrieve a 401 error.
I think it’s due to the LocalStrategy in NestJS

Here is the part in the local.strategy.ts file

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      usernameField: 'userLogin',
      passwordField: 'userPassword',
    });
  }

  async validate(userLogin: string, userPassword: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(userLogin, userPassword);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Here is the part in the app.controller.ts file

```
  @Public()
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('auth/login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return this.authService.login(req.user);
  }
```

But I don’t know how to change it.
If somebody have an example it build be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested with curl locally on server (without nginx).
I saw my error (mysql access to test the user), it was not due to nginx configuration.